# chartist graph color change

Tags: html, css, angularjs, chartist.js

I am using a chartist graph and the colours are defined in a framework level, but i need to change it in for a specific graph, so i cannot change in the frame work level, tried to create a .less file but still the changes are not reflecting.

is there any other option on how to change the colour of a bar graph and if i add more bars, the colours should be different.

PS : link for the frame work changes for chartist.
https://github.com/capitalone/Hygieia/tree/master/UI/src/app/chartist

color change need to be done in 
https://github.com/capitalone/Hygieia/blob/master/UI/src/components/widgets/build/build.less

wrote a piece of code given in .less file , but it's not reflecting... any inputs please.

```
 .ct-series-a .ct-bar {
  stroke: white;
  stroke-width: 20px;
}
.ct-series-b .ct-bar {
      stroke: blue;
      stroke-width: 20px;
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I know this answer may be quite late but I found a java script solution from [this link](http://gionkunz.github.io/chartist-js/getting-started.html#colour-up-your-charts), It shows how you can dynamically color different components.

```
var chart = new Chartist.Bar('#barChart', data, options, responsiveOptions);
    chart.on('draw', function(context) {


      if(context.type === 'bar') {
         context.element.attr({
          style: 'stroke:  red'
        });
      }else if(context.type === 'point') {
            context.element.attr({
            style: 'stroke:  blue'
        });
      }else if(context.type === 'line') {
          context.element.attr({
            style: 'stroke:  green'
        });
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I just setup a group of css (less) for each chart.

```
.profit-chart {
    .ct-series-a {
        .ct-area {
            fill: #158BE9;
        }

        .ct-bar, .ct-line, .ct-point, .ct-slice-donut {
            stroke: #158BE9;
        }
    }

    .ct-series-b {
        .ct-area {
            fill: #73b5eb;
        }

        .ct-bar, .ct-line, .ct-point, .ct-slice-donut {
            stroke: #73b5eb;
            /*stroke-dasharray: 5px;*/
        }
    }

    .ct-series-c {
        .ct-area {
            fill: #f28e2b;
        }

        .ct-bar, .ct-line, .ct-point, .ct-slice-donut {
            stroke: #f28e2b;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`less` files are not css, they need to be compiled into css. [Get any compiler on github](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=less%20compiler) or [at lesscss.org](http://lesscss.org/usage/#third-party-compilers).

Comment: I am using gulp and after saving the less file, do you want me to run gulp serve command after saving , but in my command window, it shows that the files got changed.

Comment: This is the code for my .less file trying to change the color codes for the bar graph.
      
 `.ct-chart .ct-series .ct-series-a .ct-bar  {`
`        stroke: #007f00;`
    `}`